# Desired HTTP response code when unable to delete a resource

Tags: http

I have a entity with possible links to other entities.
I want to block user from deleting the entity is it is still linked to other entities.
I wonder which HTTP error code should I return.

- 403 - Forbidden - doesn't seem to fit because it is a matter of permissions
- 409 - Conflict - usually refers unsynced update

Any suggestions?

Comment: 409 looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

409 is defined as:

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict.

This seems to be your use case - after removal of the links the DELETE would succeed.